# icon size in texstudio

Tags: texstudio

I am new. I have a question about the icons in the texstudio IDE for tex: the icons in both the tool bar and in the left panel are pretty small. Is there a way to enlarge them a little bit? 
Thanks very much.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a question that belongs to TeX.SX

Comment: Probably is off topic, but [this thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907840/thread/0a0caec2/) may help.

Comment: `Preferences->Gui scaling` [works for version 2.10]